# If New Delhi is listed as #1 on the visa under "places to be visited", can I arrive in Goa first?

Tags: visas, air-travel, india, new-delhi, goa-india

[image]

This question is on the behalf of my friend from Spain. She has a visa for India, and under the "places to be visited" section is:

1. New Delhi
2. Jaipur

But her plan has changed and she wants to land directly in Goa. Will it create any problem?

Does she has to arrive in New Delhi first?

Comment: The e-Tourist Visa won't even have any such information printed on it.

Answer (score 3):

No, its not a problem. No one will verify the exact itinerary that you've listed. Enjoy your trip.